# Authentication in .net

Tags: c#, authentication, jaas

I'd like my application, written in C#, to perform authentications, just like I used to do in Java through JAAS. Which objects should I use? Which classes? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is this [tag:winforms], [tag:webforms], [tag:wpf]...?

Answer (score 5):

> The .NET Framework uses role-based security with principal, identity,
>   and permission classes to handle security. You can choose one of the
>   built-in security modules within the .NET Framework, rather than
>   building one yourself. When you convert Java Authentication and
>   Authorization Service (JAAS) applications to the .NET Framework, you
>   must take into account the differences between the two approaches to
>   security.
>
> All JAAS configuration files must be renamed as JAAS.config to be
>   processed by Java Language Conversion Assistant. These are converted
>   to App.config files, which can be used by support-class methods to
>   obtain authentication modules and register them with the
>   authentication manager.
>
> The LoginContext class is converted to the static
>   System.Security.AuthenticationModule class, which has different
>   behavior.
>
> The LoginModule class is converted to the IAuthenticationModule
>   interface. In the Java language, the LoginContext object registers a
>   LoginModule object, which uses callback handlers to request input from
>   the user and login module to authenticate users. In the .NET
>   Framework, authentication modules are registered with the
>   authentication manager, which loops through registered authentication
>   modules to return authorization information.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82tywhc6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, better answer than mine, as it is tailored to OP's existing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming asp.net.

The MSDN page detailing [asp.net authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) provides a good overview. It can be as simple as editing the web.config file in some cases.